# CSS - Stop white-space from overflowing onto padding

Tags: css

I want the text to not wrap `white-space: nowrap` and for overlapped content to be hidden `overflow: hidden`, but I **DO** still want there to be 20px padding on either side (eg, text in coloured boxes to be 20px away from edges).

I couldn't seem to find a good answer on SO already. Pointers would be much appreciated.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.col {
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <p>1a Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris felis orci, tempor vehicula pretium vel, commodo et elit. Donec vitae lacinia turpis. Nulla scelerisque, augue a pulvinar elementum, sapien elit porta ex, et aliquet nisi felis vitae nunc. Morbi aliquam mollis arcu a ultrices. Integer accumsan sapien eros, a posuere mauris hendrerit et. Curabitur interdum scelerisque mattis. Quisque a erat metus. Donec sit amet efficitur lacus. Morbi sodales, nulla imperdiet volutpat porta, justo massa sagittis nisl, nec lacinia magna purus ac nisl. Duis ultrices, est sit amet cursus rutrum, nisl lacus consectetur lectus, at pretium nulla massa non erat</p>
    <p>1b Cras commodo ultricies mi. Vivamus quis ex imperdiet, pharetra mauris vitae, mattis justo. Aenean eget ultrices magna. Suspendisse rutrum tristique dolor quis porttitor. Aliquam pulvinar vulputate lacinia. Donec dictum efficitur ipsum, quis ullamcorper dui tincidunt sollicitudin. Phasellus tristique bibendum tincidunt. Phasellus sagittis vehicula ligula, ac sollicitudin velit condimentum maximus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum cursus lectus nisi, non dictum sapien ullamcorper in. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>2a Cras tristique diam a aliquet sollicitudin. Donec vehicula dui ipsum, eget imperdiet neque porta nec. Donec vestibulum iaculis arcu imperdiet malesuada. Sed mattis ex eu ipsum bibendum, lobortis condimentum urna maximus. Integer vehicula ipsum lacus. Pellentesque vel lacus felis. In sed interdum eros. Fusce et scelerisque mauris. Donec vel egestas elit. Maecenas in ligula ac ipsum tempus hendrerit. Pellentesque quis lacinia augue. Integer vehicula nisi rutrum, egestas eros id, euismod nisl. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo tortor, bibendum ornare turpis vel, fermentum tempus enim</p>
    <p>2b Nulla nec tempor felis. Donec auctor, leo sed vehicula egestas, nunc dui pharetra lorem, sit amet consequat risus dolor ac velit. Aenean tempus semper sapien, sollicitudin sagittis enim tristique nec. Mauris leo lacus, maximus ut convallis quis, pretium a ipsum. Aenean vel finibus urna. Donec dolor nunc, tincidunt et turpis quis, scelerisque euismod purus. Donec eu hendrerit sem. Vestibulum sed sodales lectus, vel semper lorem. Nunc sit amet est purus</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `overflow` should be set on the `<p>`:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.col {
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col > p {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <p>1a Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris felis orci, tempor vehicula pretium vel, commodo et elit. Donec vitae lacinia turpis. Nulla scelerisque, augue a pulvinar elementum, sapien elit porta ex, et aliquet nisi felis vitae nunc. Morbi aliquam mollis arcu a ultrices. Integer accumsan sapien eros, a posuere mauris hendrerit et. Curabitur interdum scelerisque mattis. Quisque a erat metus. Donec sit amet efficitur lacus. Morbi sodales, nulla imperdiet volutpat porta, justo massa sagittis nisl, nec lacinia magna purus ac nisl. Duis ultrices, est sit amet cursus rutrum, nisl lacus consectetur lectus, at pretium nulla massa non erat</p>
    <p>1b Cras commodo ultricies mi. Vivamus quis ex imperdiet, pharetra mauris vitae, mattis justo. Aenean eget ultrices magna. Suspendisse rutrum tristique dolor quis porttitor. Aliquam pulvinar vulputate lacinia. Donec dictum efficitur ipsum, quis ullamcorper dui tincidunt sollicitudin. Phasellus tristique bibendum tincidunt. Phasellus sagittis vehicula ligula, ac sollicitudin velit condimentum maximus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum cursus lectus nisi, non dictum sapien ullamcorper in. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>2a Cras tristique diam a aliquet sollicitudin. Donec vehicula dui ipsum, eget imperdiet neque porta nec. Donec vestibulum iaculis arcu imperdiet malesuada. Sed mattis ex eu ipsum bibendum, lobortis condimentum urna maximus. Integer vehicula ipsum lacus. Pellentesque vel lacus felis. In sed interdum eros. Fusce et scelerisque mauris. Donec vel egestas elit. Maecenas in ligula ac ipsum tempus hendrerit. Pellentesque quis lacinia augue. Integer vehicula nisi rutrum, egestas eros id, euismod nisl. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo tortor, bibendum ornare turpis vel, fermentum tempus enim</p>
    <p>2b Nulla nec tempor felis. Donec auctor, leo sed vehicula egestas, nunc dui pharetra lorem, sit amet consequat risus dolor ac velit. Aenean tempus semper sapien, sollicitudin sagittis enim tristique nec. Mauris leo lacus, maximus ut convallis quis, pretium a ipsum. Aenean vel finibus urna. Donec dolor nunc, tincidunt et turpis quis, scelerisque euismod purus. Donec eu hendrerit sem. Vestibulum sed sodales lectus, vel semper lorem. Nunc sit amet est purus</p>
  </div>
</div>
```